# Resizing a logo for homepage

Tags: javascript, html, image-resizing, graphical-logo

I'm relatively new to JavaScript.  Here is the code for the html index page showing the body and the logo xxcloud.gif (which I want to resize).

```
<body  id="page1">
        <div class="tail-top">
            <div class="tail-bottom">
                <div class="main">
                    <div id="header">
                        <ul>
                 <li class="first"><a href="index.html" class="current">Home page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index-1.html">Company</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index-2.html">Registration</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index-3.html">IT Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index-4.html">Questionnaire</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index-5.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        ...
                        ...

                        <div><a href="index.html"><img alt="" src="images/xxcloud.gif"  
                        class="logo" id="resizeLogo" /></a><br /></div>
```

The JavaScript code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            window.onresize = function() {
                                resizeToScreen(document.getElementById("resizeLogo"), 35);
                            };
                            /* 
                             * logo resize
                             */
                            function resizeToScreen(element, percent)
                            {
                                var wHeight = window.innerHeight;
                                var objHeight = wHeight * (percent / 100);
                                element.style.height = objHeight + "px";

                                var wWidth = window.innerWidth;
                                var objWidth = wWidth * (percent / 100);
                                element.style.width = objWidth + "px";
                            }
                        </script>
```

The id should probably be in the div tag.  The question is how can I make the logo resize when clicking on it and dragging it to make it larger or smaller.

I'm new to this site but some people prefer to write the solution in JQuery rather than JavaScript. What are the benefits of using Jquery?

Thanks in advance

Dave

//Edit alternatively: I could use ??

```
window.onresize = function(){  document.getElementById("resizelogo").style.height = "15%";
                               document.getElementById("resizelogo").style.width = "15%"; }
```

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library that provides functions for lots of common tasks and can be used to simplify your code or provide a thorough set of helper functions. I would recommend against auto-scaling non-vector graphics as it doesn't tend to leave your image looking very good.

Comment: is there a possible solution where you can increase decrease the graphic by a small amount.  Even if the solution is not practical, I would like to be able to use resize, just if it means getting to grips with the theory!  Do people know jquery rather than javascript in the industry?

Comment: I'm not going to address scaling images by clicking & dragging because I won't be able to provide a suitable answer. A one-time resize should work similarly to what you have so far. jQuery vs. JS isn't either/or. You will still be using and writing JS even if you are also using jQuery, but many things will be simpler to do in jQuery. Having the JS knowledge to do those things is good, but being able to utilize libraries to simplify your work is also good. jQuery isn't the only library that provides these sort of simplifications + helpers. Prototype, Ext, YUI, & MooTools are examples of others.

Comment: Setting your width and height to a percentage should only need to be done once, instead of as a resize handler. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjc343/cpZj9/) for a demonstration.

Comment: TY for the demonstration. I understand that you don't want to go into resizing dynamically.  However a more practical solution would be onHover and a larger image could reappear.  I would be grateful if other coders keep this discussion going.

Comment: JQuery is perfect for this stuff. JQueryUI can do lots of animation too.  Why stress yourself out reinventing code others have written, and so well.  It abstracts away the complication so that you can focus on your functional objective.